# Easy way to get and set pixels on writeablebitmap

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I need to get and set pixel in universal app (windows phone rt, windows 8.1). And I cannot find way.
When I do that in `wpf` first I calculate `stride` like:

```
int stride = wb.PixelWidth * (wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
```

After that converting to byte array

```
byte[] data = new byte[stride * wb.PixelHeight];
wb.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
```

and after that is easy:

```
for (int y = 0; y < wb.PixelHeight; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < wb.PixelWidth; ++x)
    {
        var index = (y * stride) + (x * 4);
        data[index + 3]=255;
        data[index + 2]=255 
        data[index + 1]=255 
        data[index]=255 
    }
}
```

But when i use universal app i cannot find way for something similar. I cannot use `savejpeg` because it only work in silverlight, i dont have `writeablebitmap.Format` etc.

Please help, any suggestion are welcome.
Thanx

Comment: https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Aybe thanx , this solve my problem :)

Comment: You just met your new best friend for bitmap-related operations ;-)